# How to implement square root and exponentiation on arbitrary length numbers?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, types, numbers

I'm working on new data type for arbitrary length numbers (only non-negative integers) and I got stuck at implementing square root and exponentiation functions (only for natural exponents). Please help.

I store the arbitrary length number as a string, so **all operations are made char by char**.

Please **don't** include advices to use different (existing) library or other way to store the number than string. It's meant to be a programming exercise, not a real-world application, so optimization and performance are not so necessary.

If you include code in your answer, I would prefer it to be in either pseudo-code or in C++. The important thing is the algorithm, not the implementation itself.

*Thanks for the help.*

Comment: "I got stuck at implementing square root and exponentiation functions"?  Stuck with what?  Post some code or some pseudo-code for your algorithm clearly defining what you mean by "stuck".

Comment: *I store the arbitrary length number as a string* - In what base? 10?

Comment: "I store the arbitrary length number as a string" -- Wait, wat? Not only that's a mind-boggling waste of memory (and, to an extent I cannot judge, performance potential), I also imagine this is needlessly hard to handle...

Comment: What functions do you have already implemented? How?

Comment: @S.Lott: I couldn't think of any algorithm, that would do the square root and the only thing I tried with the exponentiation is to multiply the number by itself n times (for the n-th power) and I thought that there cpuld be a more effective way of doing this. I currently don't have any existing piece of code.

Comment: @Mark Byers: In decimal base.

Comment: @tomp If you "don't have any existing piece of code", start with long addition and multiplication.

Comment: NOTE that the Square Root will fall outside your domain, unless you want just an integer approximation.

Comment: @belisarius: I currently have the basic operators +, -, *, div and mod. I used the same procedure that I would use if I had two long numbers and a piece of paper, the same algorithms that are taught in elementary schools.

Comment: @belisarius: You're right, sorry I didn't mention it in the answer, the square root is just the approximation (the floor of the value).

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thanks for the advice, I plan to read TAOCP after my exams. I will try to search more next time. ;)

Comment: @tomp good luck with your exams and please note I wasn't meaning to sound harsh, just offering honest heart felt opinions and advice!

Comment: @tomp: "I have no trouble with web search, I use it all the time, especially when programming. For this question I just chose the SO way".  A bad choice.  Please use web search **always**.  Also, please mark your homework with the [homework] tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Square root: [Babylonian method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_Method). I.e.

```
function sqrt(N):
    oldguess = -1
    guess = 1
    while abs(guess-oldguess) > 1:
        oldguess = guess
        guess = (guess + N/guess) / 2
    return guess
```

Exponentiation: [by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

```
function exp(base, pow):
    result = 1
    bits = toBinary(powr)
    for bit in bits:
        result = result * result
        if (bit):
            result = result * base
    return result
```

where `toBinary` returns a list/array of 1s and 0s, MSB first, for instance as implemented by this Python function:

```
def toBinary(x):
    return map(lambda b: 1 if b == '1' else 0, bin(x)[2:])
```

Note that if your implementation is done using binary numbers, this can be implemented using bitwise operations without needing any extra memory. If using decimal, then you will need the extra to store the binary encoding.

However, there is a decimal version of the algorithm, which looks something like this:

```
function exp(base, pow):
    lookup = [1, base, base*base, base*base*base, ...] #...up to base^9
     #The above line can be optimised using exp-by-squaring if desired

    result = 1
    digits = toDecimal(powr)
    for digit in digits:
        result = result * result * lookup[digit]
    return result
```

Comment: @David: D'oh. Fixed. Sqrt should now return the largest integer not exceeding N's square root.

Comment: Great answer. I've seen the squaring exponentiation once, but written in functional language, I just completely forgot about it. Also, I have never heard of the Babylonian method. Looks very interesting, thank you.

Comment: Your interpretation of exponentation by squaring is probably wrong. At least the 1st line of the function, e.g. `result = 1` should be `result = base` and I think the multiplication by base (on 5th line) isn't probably right either (it's not always the original base). The algorithm is easier when using recursion.

Comment: @tomp: Whoops!! Actually, `result = 1` was the only part of the function that *was* correct! I've updated it now.

Answer (score 3):

Exponentiation is trivially implemented with multiplication - the most basic implementation is just a loop,

```
result = 1;    
for (int i = 0; i < power; ++i) result *= base;
```

You can (and should) implement a better version using squaring with divide & conquer - i.e. a^5 = a^4 * a = (a^2)^2 * a.

Square root can be found using Newton's method - you have to get an initial guess (a good one is to take a square root from the highest digit, and to multiply that by base of the digits raised to half of the original number's length), and then to refine it using division: if a is an approximation to sqrt(x), then a better approximation is (a + x / a) / 2. You should stop when the next approximation is equal to the previous one, or to x / a.